# Does Datadog support graphs with 2 Y-axis with different scales?

Tags: plot, graph, datadog

Like this one:

[[image: 1]]

If yes, how do I create one?

From all documentation I've read so far, it doesn't seem to support it. But I don't see anyone confirming that it's not supported anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>2016
Confirmed on IRC (#datadog on freenode) that:</strike>

> Datadog doesn't support multiple Y-axis at this time.

2020: Now it is supported. See [James' answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150659/496289).

Comment: Now they support it! See the more recent responses for info.

Answer (score 7):

They do allow dual y-axis now

https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/widgets/timeseries/#y-axis-controls

> Introducing dual Y-axis for time series widgets.
> The time series widget on dashboards now support dual y-axis, making it easier than ever to compare two sets of data on a single graph. By removing the need to create separate graphs, your dashboards can show even more valuable information viewable at a glance.

Comment: Have you actually make it work?.

I see the documentation but there is no UI for this for me, the Y-Axis Controls only allow me to change the "left" scale and nothing else.

Comment: Hi yes - if you enable y-axis below the metrics then you will get to chose which axis its set to - see https://www.dropbox.com/s/vv32b2fhd5v8mza/datadog-y-axis.png?dl=0

Comment: In order to see this option, I need to click on 'Graph Additional: metric'.  In other words, you can't just add another query to an additional 'metric block' and expect to see the option for another y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with actually implementing this, expand the documentation for requests a bit (and/or open a support case!) and you'll find "on_right_yaxis". So, the JSON looks something like

```
 "requests": [
     {
         "formulas": [....],
         "queries": [....],
         "response_format": "timeseries",
         "style": {...},
         "display_type": "line"
     },
     {
         "on_right_yaxis": true,
         "formulas": [....],
         "queries": [....],
         "response_format": "timeseries",
         "style": {...},
         "display_type": "line"
     }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two axis have the same units but different degrees (10 vs 10 million), then using a non-linear scale such as `log` might provide what you need:

https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/203038729-Is-it-possible-to-adjust-the-y-axis-for-my-graphs-